# expect.toBeVisible is not working when I am running my Playwright test

Tags: javascript, playwright, assertion, playwright-test

I have written a script to test a website (https://www.demoblaze.com/), I am trying to validate whether the logout button is visible to the user once the login process is complete.

I am using "expect().toBeVisible()" to check the presence of the logout button, At the run time I am getting an error

```
Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(received).toBeVisible()
Call log:
  - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for locator('xpath=//a[normalize-space()=\'Log out\']')
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
```

Below is the code I am executing

```
let { test, expect } = require("@playwright/test");

test("Locator", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.demoblaze.com/");

  //click on login button using Property element
  await page.locator("#login2").click();


  //username= CSS
  await page.fill("#loginusername", "pavanol");


  //provide password =CSS
  await page.fill("input[id='loginpassword']", "test@123");

  //Click On Login - Xpath
  await page.click("//input[@id='loginpassword']");

  //verify logout button presence xpath
  const logoutLink = await page.locator("//a[normalize-space()='Log out']");
 

  //assertion
  await expect(logoutLink).toBeVisible();
  await page.close;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently don't specify a timeout when you call toBeVisible(), and the default in your code is using 5000ms, which is 5 seconds.

Perhaps it is possible that the page locater is taking longer than 5 seconds to find the logout button.

One solution you can try; from https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts:

```
await expect(logoutLink).toBeVisible({ timeout: 10000 });
```

To increase the timeout to a large enough value that it might be able to pick it up.

Await can take a really long time especially looking for elements so I think this would be a good first step.

Comment: The above suggestion is not working, still getting the error.    `Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(received).toBeVisible()
Call log:
  - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for locator('xpath=//a[normalize-space()=\'Log out\']')
  -   locator resolved to <a href="#" id="logout2" class="nav-link" onclick="…>Log out</a>
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  -   unexpected value "hidden"
  32 |   //assertion
  33 |
> 34 |   await expect(logoutLink).toBeVisible("timeout: 10000");
     |                            ^
  35 |
  36 |   await page.close;
  37 | });`

Comment: Are you sure that you have the credentials to log in? Would you try printing page in the console to see if the page got to the point of being able to see a log out button?

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct login credentials(Username: pavanol password: test@123.

Comment: I have tried to print the logout button on console and it is working

Comment: I have found out the issue, I was not clicking on the login button. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

There is not element with `#logout2` locator

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("Locator", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.demoblaze.com/");
  await page.getByRole("link", { name: "Log in" }).click();

  await page.locator("#loginusername").fill("pavanol");
  await page.locator("#loginpassword").fill("test@123");
  await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Log in" }).click();

  const logoutLink = page.getByRole("link", { name: "Log out" });
  await expect(logoutLink, "LogOut LInk doens't exist").toBeVisible({ timeout: 15_000 });
});
```